# Pycharm unable to resolve Django reference

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I pulled a project from my GitHub to my laptop.  After I install my requirements.txt file Pycharm is giving me an error "unresolved reference 'contrib/middleware'" in settings.py despite having Django installed and support enabled.   The project is working in Pycharm, I'm just getting my text highlighted and imports aren't working.  I've deleted the virtual environment, deleted the project, and pulled it again and I'm getting the same errors

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you selected virtual env in PyCharm run?

Comment: I have seleceted one.  I just left it off on the screenshot

Comment: Have you tried turn it off and on again? :)

Comment: Lol yes I have.  I've done everything except uninstall/reinstall which I'm doing next.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling.  May not be a long-term solution but it is resolved for now.